# Acer Aspire 5740 (model MS2286), do I have bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, acer

I have an Acer Aspire 5740 laptop and it has a hardware button for enabling and disabling bluetooth next to the button for toggling wifi. But when I go to System->Preferences->Bluetooth it says "No Bluetooth adapters present".

Comment: Can you be more specific on the model #? Look on the bottom or something and see if there's some other number after the 5740. That will help us determine if it came with BT or not. Thanks!

Comment: On the bottom there's written "MODEL NO. MS2286"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I own three Acer laptops, none of which have bluetooth, but all have a bluetooth switch. If you turn on the bluetooth and Ubuntu does not show that bluetooth is available, I would be confident that your laptop does not have a bluetooth module installed.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer doesn't have bluetooth hardware, but the button is there for is you select that option when you ask the hardware people to build your laptop.

It's common for OEMs to use standard parts, including standard cases and keyboards. So they have to account for all eventualities. My laptop has a bluetooth button and no bluetooth hardware for instance.

Comment: It looks like some 5740's come with BT and some don't, depending on the specific model #.

Comment: How can I found out my exact model? On the sticker there's only Aspire 5740 written.